# ffmpegの[v:0]とはどの部分？

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpegで使用する[v:0]がどの部分か理解できておりません。例えば、

> -filter_complex '[v:0]hwupload=extra_hw_frames=64,split=4[o1][o2][o3][o4],[o1]vpp_qsv=cw=1920:ch=1080:cx=0:cy=0[out1],[out1]split=3[r11][r12][r13],[r12]scale_qsv=w=1280:h=720[ro12],[r13]scale_qsv=w=960:h=540[ro13],[o2]vpp_qsv=cw=1920:ch=1080:cx=1920:cy=0[out2],[out2]split=3[r21][r22][r23],[r22]scale_qsv=w=1280:h=720[ro22],[r23]scale_qsv=w=960:h=540[ro23],[o3]vpp_qsv=cw=1920:ch=1080:cx=0:cy=1080[out3],[out3]split=3[r31][r32][r33],[r32]scale_qsv=w=1280:h=720[ro32],[r33]scale_qsv=w=960:h=540[ro33],[o4]vpp_qsv=cw=1920:ch=1080:cx=1920:cy=1080[out4],[out4]split=3[r41][r42][r43],[r42]scale_qsv=w=1280:h=720[ro42],[r43]scale_qsv=w=960:h=540[ro43]'

のようなfilter_complexがあったとして、入力は#0:0 音声、#0.1が映像です。
[0:1]や[0:v]で映像を指定するのはわかりますが、[v:0]とはどのような入力になりますでしょうか。

ご存知の方、ご教示お願いしたくよろしくお願いします。

Comment: [v:0] は [0:v:0] の省略形です。

Comment: 最初のインプットファイルの最初のビデオの動画ということですね。